# How property caching works in the following code?

Tags: python

I'm confused about the following code snippet how it works? It's a decorator and it will lazily initialize the property and then use the cached property on next requests. Looking at the code, it seems that it will always call the self.method? A little explanation will be helpful

```
class cached_property(object):
    def __init__(self, method, name=None):
        self.method = method
        self.name = name or method.__name__
        self.__doc__ = method.__doc__
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        result = self.method(inst)
        setattr(inst, self.name, result)
        return result
```

Comment: with out knowledge of a context this is hard to say what this code do

Comment: All of the magic is done by `setattr(inst, self.name, result)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks like it calls the method the first time around `result = self.method(inst)`.  It then replaces the method on the instance with the result:  `setattr(inst,self.name,result)`.

On subsequent `my_instance.my_cached_property`, you're actually accessing the (initial) result of the method (as a regular attribute) as opposed to the descriptor (the original method and the descriptor class are no bound to the class since you overwrote that attribute).

Comment: This works because `cached_property` is a non-data descriptor. If it had a `__set__` method to directly set the result in `inst.__dict__`, Python would use the data descriptor instead of the instance attribute.

Comment: @eryksun -- Yes, I suppose I should have mentioned that `cached_property` can't have `__set__` -- Otherwise as you say, `setattr` would call `cached_property.__set__(...)`.

Comment: To clarify, if it had the setter `def __set__(self, inst, val): vars(inst)[self.name] = val`, then `setattr` would set the attribute in the instance dict as before, but this wouldn't override the descriptor, i.e. `getattr(inst, name)` would still call `cached_property.__get__`.